# Matters.json date range filter

Tags: clio-api

The Clio APIV4 documentation is not very clear to me on what is expected for creating a date range filter for the open_date field in a call to matters.json. 
Can someone give me some guidance on what is expected for the filter for something like a range of all matters opened between 1/1/2019 and 1/15/2019? I also don't see if the dates are expected an ISO-8601 timestamp or not.

Comment: An update: I've tried some various formats for this and it just returns all matters:
/api/v4/matters.json?open_date>=2019-03-01<=2019-03-31
or
/api/v4/matters.json?open_date>=2019-03-01&open_date<=2019-03-31

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has this issue - I received this from Clio support:

*An example of a request for your Matters data where the Open Date lies between 01/01/2019 and 01/08/2019 would be as follows:

app.clio.com/api/v4/matters?fields=&open_date[]=>2019-01-01&open_date[]=<2019-08-01

As you can probably tell from that example, the dates you are filtering for do not need to be a timestamp. It can just be a date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD.*